# Google chrome refuses to execute javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a website runned on shared hosting on domain http://www.ssmp-almaty.kz/new/. I am using Yii2 framework in subfolder. But suddenly Google Chrome refuses to execute my javascript files giving error: Refused to execute script from 'http://www.ssmp-almaty.kz/new/js/plugins.js' because its MIME type ('application/x-httpd-php') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. Can you help me to understand what is the problem is this?
    `<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="media/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Carousel.init({
            target: $('.carousel')
        });
    </script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

As user Brian White said in a previous question related to this:

> Google updates automatically about every 6 weeks. There were probably checks added to the inclusion of Javascript files to help prevent problems executing bad files or thwart some security threat.

[Here is that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797825/refused-to-execute-script-due-to-mime-type-issue-javascript-google-chrome).

Hope that helps!

Comment: In this way I don't understand why Google recognized them as bad files and refused all javascript files.

Comment: @user2013161 can you add the code in question of your request to the post?

Comment: I posted the code where I output that libraries. Is that enough or should I demonstrate full code?

Comment: Is your server configured to output the right MIME type?

Comment: As I wrote before, I use the shared hosting. That should be the configured right, because the website located on the root works correctly.

Comment: Ahh, but "_should_ be configured right" is sometimes the problem. Try removing the `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header and see what happens.

Comment: ok, I wrote to hoster to remove that header. So I will write response from them as soon as possible.

Comment: @user2013161 any luck?

Comment: My host said that you have to use Content-type for you javascript files.

Comment: I have noticed response headers of javascript files. They are x-application-httpd.

Comment: Well, editing .htaccess file gived satisfied result                                <FilesMatch "(\.js)$">
 Header set Content-Type text/javascript
</FilesMatch>